# Tags created by select2 don't load correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I am using `select2` to make my tags look better and have a problem with saving and loading those tags.

I have this field for tags:

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

And I am setting a `select2` to that field like this:

```
$('#content_tag_list').select2
    tags: []
    tokenSeparators: [ ',' ]
    formatNoMatches: ->
      ''
```

As you can see I am using "," separator for tags. While I type tags they are correctly separated by "," but the problem is when I save that form and click on edit again, the tags are merged into one tag. For example:

1. Open edit page
2. Start typing tagas "one", "two" and "three"
3. Tags are correctly separated by ","
4. Click on button to save the content
5. Tags are saved in database separately as they should
6. Click again to edit the same content
7. Tags are displayed as like they are merged: "one two three"

If I click save after that again, content won't be connected to old tags anymore. it will be connected only with merged tag "one two three".

Any ideas why is this happening? Thank you.